# VHDL Shift Register not rotating right

Tags: vhdl, shift

Can someone help me figure out why my shift register won't rotate right. I know its not the switch inputs because I switched sw(14) with sw(15) and it still rotated left but not right. I think it is something in the actual coding but I'm not sure what.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity question2 is
Port (
      led: buffer std_logic_vector (9 downto 0);
      clk: in std_logic;
      btnU: in std_logic; 
      btnD: in std_logic;
      btnC: in std_logic; 
      sw: in std_logic_vector (15 downto 14)--------rotate prob. is not in switches
 );

end question2;

architecture Behavioral of question2 is

      constant active: std_logic :='1';

      signal DataIn:  std_logic_vector (9 downto 0):= "0000000001";  
      signal Load:    std_logic := btnD;
      signal Reset:   std_logic := btnC;  
      signal Left:    std_logic:= sw(15);
      signal Right:   std_logic:= sw(14);
      signal DataOut: std_logic_vector (9 downto 0);
      signal Clear: std_logic:= btnU;
      signal speed_enable: std_logic; 

begin

led<= DataOut;

SpeedControl: process (clk, Reset)
                    variable counter: integer range 0 to 10000000;
               begin
                    speed_enable<=not active;  
                    if Reset = Active then
                        counter:= 0; 
                    elsif (rising_edge (clk)) then 
                        counter := counter + 1; 
                        if (counter=10000000) then 
                            speed_enable<= Active; 
                            counter:=0; 
                        end if; 
                    end if; 
                end process; 

shiftregister: process(clk, clear)

        begin
        if rising_edge (clk) then 
            if clear= active or reset=active then   
                DataOut <= (others => '0');  
            elsif load = active then 
                DataOut <= DataIn ;   
            elsif Left = active and Right = not active then
                if speed_enable = active then 
                     DataOut <= DataOut(8 downto 0) & DataOut(9) ; 
            elsif  Right = active and left = not active then 
                if speed_enable = active then      
                     DataOut <= DataOut(0) & DataOut (9 downto 1) ; 
            else
                   dataout <= "0000000000";
                end if; 
            end if;
            end if;  
        end if; 
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't fixed all the problems I mentioned on your last question. Default assignments are not default connections; your `Left` and `Right` signals won't change when your `sw` input changes.

You should connect the internal control signals to your inputs right below the `led<= DataOut;` line with something like `Left <= sw(15);`

Furthermore, when no control signals are active `dataout` should be unchanged, not reset itself to all `'0'`s. Your load, reset, and clear buttons aren't going to work either. `speed_enable` is still mixing combinational assignments and clocked assignments and won't synthesize.

`DataIn` might as well be a constant since there is no way to modify it.

It also looks like you're missing the `end if;` for the clock enables (you stick them at the end instead of where they should be) which will cause undesired behavior.